# presentViewController() pops the view behind the last view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to perform a transition to another UIViewController in another storyboard but the problem is that the view that I want to display pops behind the view where I'm from.
I know that because my app includes a Snapchat-like navigation between views, so I can drag the view to the left or the right and I can see the view behind.

Here is how I attempt to do that :

```
@IBAction func account(sender: UIButton) {
    if self._isOnline {
        self.pageController?.reverseViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    else {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "blablablabla", message: "blablablabla", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SignUpLogin", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }))
        presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

With `SignUpLogin` that is the name of my second .storyboard file, here I'm in `Heart.storyboard`.
The action takes place in a `UIAlertController`, if the user press no, nothing append, if he press yes he's supposed to be redirected to the initial view of my `SignUpLogin.storyboard` file.

[image: O]

My problem come from the view at the bottom left corner. And if I use the code above in the view at the top right corner, that works ! Why ?

I have no idea of how I can do differently.

Comment: can u show some screenshots to explain what you need ?

Comment: From your posted code, nothing looks wrong. Can you post more code or screenshots?

Comment: Please show the full method where you call this code.

Comment: @JAL Thank's all, here is more code and details, sorry for that. If you want more information let me know.

Comment: @DookieMan Ok so that's not coming from these 3 lines of code... I've added the full method

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I don't know what screenshot can be relevant but I just want to make a transition between two view in two different .storyboard. But as I said, the view from where I start stay in front of the on where I want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem !

```
    @IBAction func account(sender: UIButton) {
    if self._isOnline {
        self.pageController?.reverseViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    else {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: Constants.LocalizedJoinOurBand, message: Constants.LocalizedNeedToCreatAnAccount, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.LocalizedNo, style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.LocalizedYes, style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in

            if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SignUpLogin", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
            }
        }))
        presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I don't know why in this case particularly but I have to directly set the `rootViewController` of my AppDelegate with this line :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```